# Should I say "education for women" or "education of women"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Given the following pie charts:

> [image]
>   The pie charts above show the highest level of education of women in Someland in 1945 and in 2005.

I have been told that the following sentence should be corrected as follows:

**Original sentence**

> - The two pie charts compare the highest level of education **of** women in
>     Someland between 1945 and 2005 as percentage of the entire female
>     population

**Corrected sentence**

> - The two pie charts compare the highest level of education **for** women in
>     Someland between 1945 and 2005 as percentage of the entire female
>     population

Why is the original sentence wrong?

Comment: You have '**of** for' and '**for** for' in your sentences. Is that what you meant to type?

Comment: Both are wrong...

Comment: Sorry. I have just corrected the mistake

Comment: It is difficult to give a cogent rationale without being able to see the actual pie charts.

Comment: @CarSmack I have just added the image with the pie charts

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean, 'the highest level of education **achieved by**/**reached by**/**held by** women? If so I actually prefer the first phrase. So, yes, 'level of education of women' is correct. But the other phrase is also okay.

Details:

In this context, I actually prefer

'the highest level of education **of** women in Someland'

One reason I like this phrasing is that it can have the meaning:

'the highest level of education **achieved by** women', and that seems to be the exact meaning in the pie charts: what is the highest level of education **achieved by** or **held by** women in 1945 and in 2005.

As for

'the highest level of education **for** women in Someland'

it means

'the highest level of education **with regard to** women in Someland.'

So that is also okay in this context. But to me, it is perhaps not as strong a statement as the first phrase.

In fact the second phrase *can* (but does not have to) mean

'the highest level of education **available to** women in Someland'. And we know that just because something is available to someone, it does not mean that they will take advantage of it. You can lead a horse to water but you can't make it drink. But in the context of the pie charts, this is not the meaning.

So again, either phrase is fine. I prefer the first one. Some people may not like the first phrase because of the repetition of the word *of* in it. But sometimes one cannot avoid repetition. (EDIT: If you really wanted to get on someone nerves, you could say 'the highest level of eductaion of women of Someland' - ha). Both phrases are natural, common, and contemporary.

I am curious who told you to make the "correction" and why they told you that. Was it a native speaker? It was your teacher, just make the change because that is what they think is better.